# am using selectize but I can not change color of option list

Tags: html

```
            <select name="user_id"  data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom>
                <option style="color:red" value='1'>Okay</option>
              <option style="color:blue" value='2'>Okay</option>
                <option value='3'>Okay</option>
            </select>
```

I just want to change color of text in option to red. Any help?

Comment: you want to set the styling on select, not the option. you could put an event handler on the option and handle it with javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

Just hang an event handler on it with jquery and change the color depending on the data-col value
https://jsfiddle.net/b3m72saw/3/

```
<select id='test' name="user_id" data-md-selectize data-md-selectize-bottom>
  <option  data-col='red'value='1'>red</option>
  <option data-col="green" value='1'>green</option>
  <option data-col="yellow" value='1'>yellow</option>
  <option data-col="blue" value='1'>blue</option>
</select>
```

```
$('#test').click(function() {
  $(this).css('color', $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-col'));
  $(this).children().css('color','black');
});
```

Comment: sorry. did not realize you where using a plugin. my mistake, in that case i don't really know